# Automapper doesn't map Generic collection of T to Generic collection of TD

Tags: c#, automapper

Hello I've wrote a generic method for mapping DTO to POCO and Vice versa. however when i pass a list of POCO it doesn't map it to list of DTO. look below:

```
public static class BaseMapper<T, TD>
    where T : class
    where TD : class
{
    public static List<TD> Map(List<T> entity)
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<List<T>, List<TD>>());
        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        return mapper.Map<List<TD>>(entity);
    }

    public static List<T> Map(List<TD> dto)
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<List<TD>, List<T>>());
        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        return mapper.Map<List<T>>(dto);
    }

}
```

here is my POCO:

```
public partial class Company : Core
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Company Virtual Properties
/// </summary>
public partial class Company
{
    public virtual ICollection<Cartable> Cartables { get; } = new HashSet<Cartable>(); 
}
```

here is my DTO

```
public class CompanyDTO : CoreDTO
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

This method returns `List<Company>` which has records then i use map to get a `List<CompanyDTO>` then its null.

```
using static BaseMapper<Company, CompanyDTO>;
public Response<List<CompanyDTO>> GetAll(Guid currentUserId, int pageNum, int pageSize)
{
    var ProcessResponse = new Response<List<CompanyDTO>>();
    try
    {
        var entities = _unitOfWork.Companies.Query().OrderBy(x => x.Title).Skip(pageNum * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
        ProcessResponse.Result = Map(entities); //it turns out null here. 
        ProcessResponse.RecCount = _unitOfWork.Companies.Query().Count();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ProcessResponse.Failed(ex.Message, ex.InnerException.Message);
    }
    return ProcessResponse;
}
```

Comment: You've totally misunderstood how AM is supposed to be used, so you should either read the docs to understand it or just map by hand.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu have i? mind explaining what have i totally misunderstood? i've done as document said

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu i am not mapping child lists basically just mapping `title` to `title` but as a list. https://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Lists-and-arrays.html

Comment: people on this website are so ignorant even if they don't understand the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a mapping for the entity type, not the collection type.
I.e.

```
new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<TD, T>());
```

instead of

```
new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<List<TD>, List<T>>());
```

Then it will work.

P.S. Automapper has really good documentation - did you not try read? https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Lists-and-arrays.html